# html <a> link converting itself to IP address

Tags: html, mediawiki

I have a few links, one of which is converting the URL in the browser to the IP address of the server when the user clicks it and I have no idea why:

```
<a href="http://myserver.com/a.php">a</a>
<a href="http://myserver.com/b.php">b</a>
<a href="http://myserver.com/wiki/index.php">d</a>
<a href="http://myserver.com/c.html">c</a>
```

a, b, and c show `http://myserver.com/a.php`, but when I click on the wiki link I get `1.2.3.4/wiki/index.php` and I can't figure out how to get this url to properly reflect the domain name.

I've tried using a relative link `/wiki/index.php`, and changing the URL slightly `http://myserver.com/wiki/`

Any ideas?

Why the downvotes?  This is a completely valid question....

Comment: Does that page exist?

Comment: sounds like some sort of redirection on the server side, can you see any traces of that on your browser's dev tools panel?

Comment: For starters, your HTML is wrong. Ex `<a href="http://myserver.com/a.php"</a>` should be `<a href="http://myserver.com/a.php">something</a>`

Comment: yes.  The hyperlink works, it just replaces `myserver.com` with `1.2.3.4` in the browser's address bar.

Comment: @ochi Just about to say the same thing.

Comment: @j08691 yeah I was just typing it quickly and forgot the `>` - I fixed it.

Comment: @ochi where would I see those?

Comment: depending on your browser, for Chrome, FireFox, IE, you press F12 (on Windows) and a dev tools panel shows up.  Navigate to the Network tab and clear what's on it.  Click on your link and see the requests made by the browser (and the responses obtained)... it would tell you a lot about the interactions between the browser and the server.

Comment: Hmm... seems there might be some sort of redirect in there - as soon as I click on the link the network tab seems to refresh itself and load the wiki page.

Comment: While the question is valid, there is not enough information to troubleshoot - specially now that we suspect there is a server-side redirect (nothing on your question implies that) - try adding a [mcve] to help us, help you.  For example, you don't say if there JS involved in your code (i.e. a click event) or if there is PHP page that handles the page request (or any code in it that might be doing the redirect). - Bottom line is, links don't change themselves so something is at play but there is not enough info to narrow things down. At this point, we are just guessing at possible solutions

Comment: I'm not sure what environment you exactly use, but if you really use MediaWiki and you definitely doesn't have a redirect rule in your web-server setup, please provide the ``$wgServer``, ``$wgScriptPath`` and ``$wgArticlePath`` variables of your MediaWiki setup (as long as you really use MediaWiki, of course).

Comment: @Florian - thank you so much!  Apparently at some stage I set my `$wgServer` path in my localsettings.php file to the IP of the server and forgot about it, hence the super broad question without a lot of specifics.  You're a lifesaver!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like I said in my comment:
Check the `$wgServer`, `$wgScriptPath` and `$wgArticlePath` configuration variables in your LocalSettings.php if they're set correctly. All these variables are used to redirect a request to the "correct" (wgServer is the *correct* url) url. So, if you've `$wgServer` set to the IP of your server, all requests to your domain will be redirected to the IP address by mediawiki.

Comment: Yeah - I must have been debugging something months ago and forgotten about it :)